# Multilevel Accordion Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I am trying to make a multilevel accordion menu for the project. My accordion menu work for 1st level, but 2 levels not working (ex.Project Information > Key Documents). HTML code generated from WordPress menu You can check live demo here

https://codepen.io/pagol/pen/qgbXGy

Please resize output window as mobile size.\

I think need to tweak my javascript a bit. bellow is my script

```
var accordion_head = $('.accordion li > a, .accordion li > li > a'),
        accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu, .accordion li > li > .sub-menu');

    // Open the first tab on load

    //accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

    // Click function

    accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

        // Disable header links

        //event.preventDefault();

        // Show and hide the tabs on click

        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
            accordion_head.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

    });
```

Mainly I want to create WordPress menu, on the desktop it will show horizontal menu and mobile it will show accordion menu. I tried many ways but failed, then I used two menu markup, one for mobile and one for me desktop. If you guys know any menu single markup which can solve my purpose then also ok too

Answer (score 0):

We can use media queries to trigger a desktop navigation and tuck it away on mobile. You can clean up your CSS to accomodate this working version but here you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVZabq

On mobile the desktop navigation disappears and the mobile navigation appears. When stretched back to desktop, mobile nav disappears and desktop menu displays.

Here's the added bits:

**HTML**

```
<div class="desktop-nav">
  <ul class="accordion">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#">Project Information</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#key-results">Key Results</a></li>
            <li><a href="#partners">Partner NGOs</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="#">Key Documents</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#key-documents/legal-framework">Legal framework</a></li>
                <li><a href="#key-documents/project-document">Project Document</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#./news-events">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#working-areas">Working Areas</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#"> Performance</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#./success-story">Success Story</a></li>
            <li><a href="#case-statistics">Case Statistics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#voices-of-the-field">Voices from the Field</a></li>
          </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.desktop-nav,
.desktop-nav ul{
  width:100%;
  display:inline;
}

.desktop-nav ul li{
  float:left;
  min-width:200px; /*Can be anything change your CSS to make how you want, demo purposes */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.desktop-nav,
.desktop-nav ul{
  display:none; <!-- Hide on screens smaller than 600px -->
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. thank for trying also. actually currently i am useing media query. so on hide and one show. but now main issue accordion 2 level not working. if go to Project Information > Key Documents, if you click on Key Documents next menu not open. now it just got off